# Create user login and password for users from csv using ImportExport Module Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-import-export

I want to create a new user's login and random/same password using CSV file using the ImportExport module Django. I've tried many examples but for no use. Can you please suggest anything? I've even tried to make password field in the import csv file. Let me know any tutorial/link that you can share to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to populate the database with dummy data, there is a module called **faker** in python.
Here is a small code snippet showing how you can use faker:

```
import os
# Configure settings for project
# Need to run this before calling models from application!
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','(YOUR DJANGO PROJECT).settings')

import django
# Import settings
django.setup()

import random
from (YOUR DJANGO APP).models import User
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()

def populate(N=5):

    for entry in range(N):

        # Create Fake Data for entry
        fake_name = fakegen.name().split()
        fake_first_name = fake_name[0]
        fake_last_name = fake_name[1]
        fake_email = fakegen.email()

        # Create new User Entry
        user = User.objects.get_or_create(first_name=fake_first_name,
                                          last_name=fake_last_name,
                                          email=fake_email)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Populating the databases...")
    populate(20)
    print('Populating Complete')
```

Comment: No not faker. I need to import users based on csv details. I'm developing an elearning platform.

Answer (score 0):

django-import-export contains [several hooks](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import_workflow.html) which you can use to manipulate data prior to insertion in the db.  This seems like the ideal way to generate a random password for each user.

You can combine this with Django's [`make_random_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password) function.  It doesn't seem like a good idea to have passwords in the import spreadsheet, but maybe you need to do that for some reason.

You will need to create your own Resource subclass, and override the `before_save_instance()`, for example:

```py
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        pw = User.objects.make_random_password()
        instance.set_password(pw)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
        import_id_fields = ['id']
```

Comment: Looks good. However, can you suggest to me a way by which we can see what password was generated to which user because after the file has been uploaded, we will need the password as well to login right.

Comment: You won't be able to see the plain text password because it is hashed, however you could generate a random string and create the password from that.  Then retain the plain text version.  Obviously doing this is a bad idea because of the security risk in storing plain text passwords, instead it would be better to require users to set a strong password at first login.

Comment: yes that sounds good.. thanks for the update.. if this works will mark your answer as selected.. but is it possible that before setting the password I can get the reference user's instance value?

Comment: you should be able to if you use the `after_save_instance()` hook